# Flexbox: How can I re-order my divs and have them on multiple rows for mobile?

Tags: flexbox

With flexbox, how can I?:

Desktop: Div one, Div two & Div three in a row.

Mobile:  Div one & Div two next to each other, with Div three underneath them.

**Desktop**

```
`<div class="parent flex items-center justify-between">
 <div class="flex flex-1>Div one</div>
 <div class="flex flex-1 sm:order-last sm:flex-col">Div two</div>
 <div class="flex flex-1>Div three</div>
 </div>`
```

**Mobile**

```
`<div class="parent flex items-center justify-between">
 <div class="flex flex-1">Div one </div>
 <div class="flex flex-1">Div three </div>
 <div class="flex flex-1 sm:order-last sm:flex-col">Div two</div>
 </div>`
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For this using `flexbox` with plain CSS you would need a combination of [`flex-wrap: wrap;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap#wrap) on the parent, a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_media_queries/Using_media_queries) to apply styles specifically to mobile/desktop and the [`order` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) to change the div's position for mobile/desktop:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  gap: .5rem;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* allow wrapping on multiple lines when required */
}

.parent > div {
  flex: 1;
}

/** styles specifically for mobile (adjust breakpoint to your needs) */
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .parent > div:nth-of-type(2) {
    /* expand second div to full width */
    flex-basis: 100%;
    /* move second div to the end */
    order: 1;
  }
}

/** styles for better visualization - just ignore them */
.parent > div {
  background: #e6e6e6;
  border: #ccc 0.125rem solid;
  text-align: center;
  padding-block: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>DIV 1</div>
  <div>DIV 2</div>
  <div>DIV 3</div>
</div>
```

Using tailwind CSS - as you seem to be doing:

```css
/** styles for better visualization - just ignore them */
div > div {
  background: #e6e6e6;
  border: #ccc 0.125rem solid;
  text-align: center;
  padding-block: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex flex-wrap gap-3">
  <div class="flex-1">DIV 1</div>
  <div class="flex-1 basis-full sm:basis-0 order-last sm:order-none">
    DIV 2
  </div>
  <div class="flex-1">DIV 3</div>
</div>

<!-- include tailwind - only for demonstration! -->
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>
```